# When to check for condition and when to use try-catch in general?

Tags: c#, exception, conditional-statements, try-catch

After many projects in c# I have come to realize that try-catch blocks can be very useful in many cases. But checking for certain conditions (ex. checking if given index is not out of bounds) can be easier and less time consuming. In smaller projects I usually could get away only using conditional statements. When should you actually expect and deal with an exception and not just check for a condition? Is there some sort of a general rule for when you should use each one?

Comment: exception catching is for *exceptional situations* we can't control (RDBMS failure; someone drop / block the file; downloaded data don't meet required format etc.). If we can check easily with `if` we should prefer doing it

Answer (score 1):

I think a good rule of thumb would be to use exception handling when the success/failure of an operation is not in the current code's scope.

For example, if you're trying to read from the serial port, but you don't know if there is a line there or not, you would want to use exception handling because there is no way to know in advance whether your readline will result in success or failure.

On the other hand, you don't want to go overboard with exception handling and use a try-catch every time you access an array when you know the size of the array. In that case the success/failure is directly within the scope of the current context; just use a conditional to check the bounds.

I'm no authority on the subject though, so take this advice with a grain of salt.

Answer (score -1):

I think when you are not aware of codes like when you open a any file and perform operation and before file closed you terminate the connection in such type of scenario u have to use ty catch...simply it's used to with more complex type...In small project there affects not a large scale...but project will be big many operation are running in parllel so try catch very useful on that condition...i hope you understand..